# Problema después de update

Tags: php, mysql

Actualmente tengo una falla en mi código y no logro conseguir la solución, estoy realizando unos update a varias tablas, entre ellas la tabla alumno y representante que están relacionadas por una clave foránea. El punto esta que si modifico la clave primaria de la tabla representantes coloque que los datos nuevos fuesen insertado en vez de modificados, ya que un representante puede tener varios alumnos. El problema esta que después de hacer ese cambio y al consultar a los alumnos con los datos del representante antiguo, puedo ver los datos y hasta tenerlos en el formulario para modificar, pero al guardar me indica que hay duplicidad de datos y hasta me entra en una función que no corresponde que entre. Tratare de insertar el código por aquí, pero agradecería a quien este dispuesto a ayudarme con esto me deje su correo para enviarle las tablas y el código ya que esto sera para mi proyecto de grado, de ante mano muchas gracias.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Resultado Modificacion</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php

$Conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","prueba2") or die ("Problemas con la Conexion");
$Registros = mysqli_query($Conexion, "select * from representantes") or die ("Problemas en la consulta de Representantes".mysqli_error($Conexion));
    $Reg = mysqli_fetch_array($Registros);


if ($Reg['CedulaRepresentante'] <> $_REQUEST['CedulaRepresentanteNuevo']) 


[

mysqli_query($Conexion, "update alumnos set CedulaAlumno = '$_REQUEST[CedulaAlumnoNuevo]', TipoCedulaAlumno = '$_REQUEST[TipoCedulaAlumnoNuevo]', PrimerApellidoAlumno = '$_REQUEST[PrimerApellidoAlumnoNuevo]', SegundoApellidoAlumno = '$_REQUEST[SegundoApellidoAlumnoNuevo]', PrimerNombreAlumno = '$_REQUEST[PrimerNombreAlumnoNuevo]', SegundoNombreAlumno = '$_REQUEST[SegundoNombreAlumnoNuevo]', FechaNacimientoAlumno = '$_REQUEST[FechaNacimientoAlumnoNuevo]', NacionalidadAlumno = '$_REQUEST[NacionalidadAlumnoNuevo]', EdadAlumno = '$_REQUEST[EdadAlumnoNuevo]', SexoAlumno = '$_REQUEST[SexoAlumnoNuevo]', DireccionAlumno = '$_REQUEST[DireccionAlumnoNuevo]', TelefonoAlumno = '$_REQUEST[TelefonoAlumnoNuevo]', CorreoAlumno = '$_REQUEST[CorreoAlumnoNuevo]', Seccion = '$_REQUEST[SeccionNuevo]', CedulaRepresentanteRef = '$_REQUEST[CedulaRepresentanteNuevo]' where CedulaAlumno = '$_REQUEST[CedulaAlumnoViejo]'") or die ("Problemas en el primer if del query alumnos select: ".mysqli_error($Conexion));



mysqli_query($Conexion, "update estatusalumno set CedulaAlumno = '$_REQUEST[CedulaAlumnoNuevo]', EstadoAlumno = '$_REQUEST[EstadoAlumnoNuevo]', InstitutoProcedencia = '$_REQUEST[InstitutoProcedenciaNuevo]', AsignaturaQueCursa = '$_REQUEST[AsignaturaQueCursaNuevo]' where CedulaAlumno = '$_REQUEST[CedulaAlumnoViejo]'") or die ("Problemas en el primer if query estatus select: ".mysqli_error($Conexion));



mysqli_query($Conexion, "insert into representantes (TipoCedulaRepresentante, CedulaRepresentante, PrimerApellidoRepresentante, SegundoApellidoRepresentante, PrimerNombreRepresentante, SegundoNombreRepresentante, NacionalidadRepresentante, EdadRepresentante, DireccionRepresentante, TelefonoRepresentante, CorreoRepresentante, ProfesionRepresentante, DireccionTrabajoRepresentante, TelefonoTrabajoRepresentante, ParentescoEstudiante, DireccionEmergencia) values ('$_REQUEST[TipoCedulaRepresentanteNuevo]', '$_REQUEST[CedulaRepresentanteNuevo]','$_REQUEST[PrimerApellidoRepresentanteNuevo]','$_REQUEST[SegundoApellidoRepresentanteNuevo]','$_REQUEST[PrimerNombreRepresentanteNuevo]', '$_REQUEST[SegundoNombreRepresentanteNuevo]', '$_REQUEST[NacionalidadRepresentanteNuevo]', '$_REQUEST[EdadRepresentanteNuevo]', '$_REQUEST[DireccionRepresentanteNuevo]', '$_REQUEST[TelefonoRepresentanteNuevo]', '$_REQUEST[CorreoRepresentanteNuevo]', '$_REQUEST[ProfesionRepresentanteNuevo]', '$_REQUEST[DireccionTrabajoRepresentanteNuevo]', '$_REQUEST[TelefonoTrabajoRepresentanteNuevo]', '$_REQUEST[ParentescoEstudianteNuevo]', '$_REQUEST[DireccionEmergenciaNuevo]')") or die ("Problemas en el primer if query Representantes select:".mysqli_error($Conexion));




mysqli_query($Conexion, "update padres set CedulaAlumno = '$_REQUEST[CedulaAlumnoNuevo]', PrimerApellidoPadres = '$_REQUEST[PrimerApellidoPadresNuevo]', SegundoApellidoPadres = '$_REQUEST[SegundoApellidoPadresNuevo]', PrimerNombrePadres = '$_REQUEST[PrimerNombrePadresNuevo]', SegundoNombrePadres = '$_REQUEST[SegundoNombrePadresNuevo]', DireccionPadres = '$_REQUEST[DireccionPadresNuevo]', TelefonoPadres = '$_REQUEST[TelefonoPadresNuevo]' where CedulaAlumno = '$_REQUEST[CedulaAlumnoViejo]'") or die ("Problemas en el primer if query padres select: ".mysqli_error($Conexion));



mysqli_query($Conexion, "update documentos set CedulaAlumno = '$_REQUEST[CedulaAlumnoNuevo]', CertificadoSaludEscolar = '$_REQUEST[CertificadoSaludEscolarNuevo]', BoletinInformativo = '$_REQUEST[BoletinInformativoNuevo]', CertificadoAprobacion = '$_REQUEST[CertificadoAprobacionNuevo]', PartidaNacimiento = '$_REQUEST[PartidaNacimientoNuevo]', CopiasPartidaNacimiento = '$_REQUEST[CopiasPartidaNacimientoNuevo]', CopiasCedulaAlumno = '$_REQUEST[CopiasCedulaAlumnoNuevo]', CopiasCedulaRepresentante = '$_REQUEST[CopiasCedulaRepresentanteNuevo]', FotoAlumno = '$_REQUEST[FotoAlumnoNuevo]', FotoRepresentante = '$_REQUEST[FotoRepresentanteNuevo]' where CedulaAlumno = '$_REQUEST[CedulaAlumnoViejo]'") or die ("Problemas en el primer if query documentos select: ".mysqli_error($Conexion));
echo "paso documentos 1°";

mysqli_close($Conexion);

echo "Los datos fueron modificados y agregados con exito";


]

else

[


mysqli_query($Conexion, "update alumnos set CedulaAlumno = '$_REQUEST[CedulaAlumnoNuevo]', TipoCedulaAlumno = '$_REQUEST[TipoCedulaAlumnoNuevo]', PrimerApellidoAlumno = '$_REQUEST[PrimerApellidoAlumnoNuevo]', SegundoApellidoAlumno = '$_REQUEST[SegundoApellidoAlumnoNuevo]', PrimerNombreAlumno = '$_REQUEST[PrimerNombreAlumnoNuevo]', SegundoNombreAlumno = '$_REQUEST[SegundoNombreAlumnoNuevo]', FechaNacimientoAlumno = '$_REQUEST[FechaNacimientoAlumnoNuevo]', NacionalidadAlumno = '$_REQUEST[NacionalidadAlumnoNuevo]', EdadAlumno = '$_REQUEST[EdadAlumnoNuevo]', SexoAlumno = '$_REQUEST[SexoAlumnoNuevo]', DireccionAlumno = '$_REQUEST[DireccionAlumnoNuevo]', TelefonoAlumno = '$_REQUEST[TelefonoAlumnoNuevo]', CorreoAlumno = '$_REQUEST[CorreoAlumnoNuevo]', Seccion = '$_REQUEST[SeccionNuevo]', CedulaRepresentanteRef = '$_REQUEST[CedulaRepresentanteNuevo]' where CedulaAlumno = '$_REQUEST[CedulaAlumnoViejo]'") or die ("Problemas en el segundo if query alumnos select: ".mysqli_error($Conexion));


mysqli_query($Conexion, "update estatusalumno set CedulaAlumno = '$_REQUEST[CedulaAlumnoNuevo]', EstadoAlumno = '$_REQUEST[EstadoAlumnoNuevo]', InstitutoProcedencia = '$_REQUEST[InstitutoProcedenciaNuevo]', AsignaturaQueCursa = '$_REQUEST[AsignaturaQueCursaNuevo]' where CedulaAlumno = '$_REQUEST[CedulaAlumnoViejo]'") or die ("Problemas en el segundo if query estatus select: ".mysqli_error($Conexion));



mysqli_query($Conexion, "update representantes set CedulaRepresentante = '$_REQUEST[CedulaRepresentanteNuevo]', TipoCedulaRepresentante = '$_REQUEST[TipoCedulaRepresentanteNuevo]',  PrimerApellidoRepresentante = '$_REQUEST[PrimerApellidoRepresentanteNuevo]', SegundoApellidoRepresentante = '$_REQUEST[SegundoApellidoRepresentanteNuevo]', PrimerNombreRepresentante = '$_REQUEST[PrimerNombreRepresentanteNuevo]', SegundoNombreRepresentante = '$_REQUEST[SegundoNombreRepresentanteNuevo]', NacionalidadRepresentante = '$_REQUEST[NacionalidadRepresentanteNuevo]', EdadRepresentante = '$_REQUEST[EdadRepresentanteNuevo]', DireccionRepresentante = '$_REQUEST[DireccionRepresentanteNuevo]', TelefonoRepresentante = '$_REQUEST[TelefonoRepresentanteNuevo]', CorreoRepresentante = '$_REQUEST[CorreoRepresentanteNuevo]', ProfesionRepresentante = '$_REQUEST[ProfesionRepresentanteNuevo]', DireccionTrabajoRepresentante = '$_REQUEST[DireccionTrabajoRepresentanteNuevo]', TelefonoTrabajoRepresentante = '$_REQUEST[TelefonoTrabajoRepresentanteNuevo]', ParentescoEstudiante = '$_REQUEST[ParentescoEstudianteNuevo]', DireccionEmergencia = '$_REQUEST[DireccionEmergenciaNuevo]' where CedulaRepresentante = '$_REQUEST[CedulaRepresentanteViejo]'") or die ("problemas en el segundo if query representante select: ".mysqli_error($Conexion));


mysqli_query($Conexion, "update padres set CedulaAlumno = '$_REQUEST[CedulaAlumnoNuevo]', PrimerApellidoPadres = '$_REQUEST[PrimerApellidoPadresNuevo]', SegundoApellidoPadres = '$_REQUEST[SegundoApellidoPadresNuevo]', PrimerNombrePadres = '$_REQUEST[PrimerNombrePadresNuevo]', SegundoNombrePadres = '$_REQUEST[SegundoNombrePadresNuevo]', DireccionPadres = '$_REQUEST[DireccionPadresNuevo]', TelefonoPadres = '$_REQUEST[TelefonoPadresNuevo]' where CedulaAlumno = '$_REQUEST[CedulaAlumnoViejo]'") or die ("Problemas en el segundo if query padres select: ".mysqli_error($Conexion));


mysqli_query($Conexion, "update documentos set CedulaAlumno = '$_REQUEST[CedulaAlumnoNuevo]', CertificadoSaludEscolar = '$_REQUEST[CertificadoSaludEscolarNuevo]', BoletinInformativo = '$_REQUEST[BoletinInformativoNuevo]', CertificadoAprobacion = '$_REQUEST[CertificadoAprobacionNuevo]', PartidaNacimiento = '$_REQUEST[PartidaNacimientoNuevo]', CopiasPartidaNacimiento = '$_REQUEST[CopiasPartidaNacimientoNuevo]', CopiasCedulaAlumno = '$_REQUEST[CopiasCedulaAlumnoNuevo]', CopiasCedulaRepresentante = '$_REQUEST[CopiasCedulaRepresentanteNuevo]', FotoAlumno = '$_REQUEST[FotoAlumnoNuevo]', FotoRepresentante = '$_REQUEST[FotoRepresentanteNuevo]' where CedulaAlumno = '$_REQUEST[CedulaAlumnoViejo]'") or die ("Problemas en el segundo if query documentos select: ".mysqli_error($Conexion));

mysqli_close($Conexion);

echo "Los datos fueron modificados con exito";  
]


?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Para que quieres modificar el campo clave de la tabla? se supone que si es campo clave este va a ser único y no puede esta repetido, por ejemplo si quieres actualizar el campo clave y el nuevo valor ya existe, te lanzara que existe duplicidad de datos. Lo que podrías actualizar es la clave foránea en la tabla que esta referenciandola.

Comment: Buenas, eso lo se, solo lo preguntaba por que un profesor en la defensa me puede decir que pasaría si cambio el id del representante y yo quedare ¬¬ por que entiendo que no se debería hacer. Pero muchas gracias, me haz quitado un peso de encima.

Comment: Por cierto, si intento modificar el campo clave, no realizo una modificación, sino un insert, por lo tano no modifico el campo clave anterior, pero cuando trato de usar un update con los datos viejos "que aun están en la tabla" no me deja, meda duplicidad y eso es lo que no entiendo.

Comment: Por favor ejecuta `DESC <tabla>` de las tablas que muestras aquí y copia el resultado en la pregunta. Eso nos permitirá ver sus estructuras DDL.

Comment: Disculpa amigo, soy nuevo aquí y no se de que herramienta me hablas, aquí les dejo la carpeta con los códigos y la base de datos, muchas gracias.
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/nfz5cfujf6cu76c/AABB8b3nBjSQDefNgHd1z9vOa?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

La clave o llave primaria es un campo, o grupo de campos que identifica en forma única un registro. Ningún otro registro puede tener la misma llave primaria. La llave primaria se utiliza para distinguir un registro con el fin de que se pueda  tener acceso a ellos, organizarlos y manipularlos. En el caso de un registro de un empleado, él numero de este representa  un ejemplo de una llave primaria.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Básicamente no se debería hacer un update a la clave primaria, ya que si la clave primaria ya existe lanzara un error de duplicidad de datos, y si no existe la clave y la anterior clave tenia registros asociados, esos registros modifican la asociación, dependiendo de como tengas creada tu tabla, al ejecutar update se podrían realizar operaciones como:

```
ON UPDATE RESTRICT
ON UPDATE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON UPDATE SET NULL
```

Como dato adicional: por lo general a los campos claves se les da la propiedad de autoincrementable, ya que se sabe que no se va a modificarlos, de otra forma se estaría rompiendo las relaciones en las tablas.

Comment: Buenas, eso eso lo entiendo perfectamente, mi clave primaria no es auto incrementable ya que son las id´s de los alumnos y sus representantes. Lo que tendré que hacer es no modificar esos campo para evitar el error.

Comment: Claro como te digo, la clave primaria es única, aunque si puedes cambiarlas pero para eso  debes hacer un update con un valor que no exista en como campo clave, y en tu tabla poner la propiedad, ON UPDATE CASCADE para que los registros asociados cambien, de lo contrario el valor por default en MYSQL es ON UPDATE RESTRICT, que no deja realizar el update por que tiene tablas asociadas,.